# How would I set the movement scale in Blender 2.79?

Tags: modeling

Now, I know how to set the global scale. What I'm concerned with is how I would set a movement scale. For example, let's say I'm extruding a cube and I need it to exactly be 20 cm/global units taller. The ideal scenario would be that in some setting, I can just take four vertices and extrude it up by 20 and it locks in as soon as I drag my mouse up. Is there any easy way of making that happen without having to resort to eyeballing or the properties menu?

Comment: you can do this with the keyboard. For example if you need to move 20cm on the Z axis you'd type: G Z .20 no mouse involved. Else you can use Snapping ( the magnet icon) and set it to "increments". This works best if you use Ortho Views where you can see a grid and how the vertices are snapping.